# How to ensure variable integrity in promises

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, firebase-admin

I am working with firebase admin for node js. I am trying to get some data from the database and store it inside of the "data" object.

```
function run(uid){
    var data = {}
    data.uid = uid
    getdata(data)
}


function getdata(data){
    var ref = admin.database().ref('users/'+data.uid);
    ref.once('value')
        .then(function(snapshot) {
            data.snapshot = snapshot.val()
            logdata(data)
        })
}

function logdata(data){
    console.log(data.uid)
}
```

the problem that I am having is that if I make the call to run(uid) twice consecutively, the console.log() statement will output the same uid (even though I pass in 2 different uids into run(uid)). I assume that the problem is due to the promise in getdata() because by the time the promise is received, the new data object has been passed into getdata(). How would I ensure that the data object passed into getdata() is the same data object as in the line "data.snapshot=snapshot.val()"?

This script is running in node.js

I have already tried declaring data with "var" as that creates a new object. This did not change anything.

Comment: That doesn't look right, are you sure that's the code you're using verbatim? The `var data = {}` inside the `run` body will create and pass along a completely new object on every call

Comment: yes I have tried that. Same result.

Comment: This seems to work as expected https://jsbin.com/fuxagahege/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine to me. I think the way you are calling the run(uid) might be a problem here. If you are using 2 uid's to fetch data from the server asynchronously, you must wait for the first request to complete and then call the run method with a new uid.

You can achieve the same with either async/await functions or by using then or in case of ajax, inside the success block of the first call, run the method run(uid) with a new uid.

This is just a sample but I think the basic logic would go something like

```
function run(uid_array){ //array list
var data = {}
//iterate uid_array
//call await getdata(uid)
//store in data as key value pair
}

async function getdata(data){
//code
}
```

Comment: "*If you are using 2 uid's to fetch data from the server asynchronously, you must wait for the first request to complete and then call the run method with a new uid.*" - why is that, is that a firebase limitation?